# PHP dateitme formatting from date()

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have an issue with the date-format that will be saved into a MySQL-table.

In the table there is a datime formatted field 'a' with default setting of '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

To initialise current date and time I set the timezone date-function like this:

```
$timezone = 'Europe/Berlin';
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

to save `$time` into the respective field 'a'. Everything works fine.

Now I thought of changing the datetime format into "d-m-Y H:i:s".

I used:

```
$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $time)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
$time = $output;
```

The problem is that this not seems to work. In the database will be inserted '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to change the format if the one you had worked?

Comment: just to expand my knowledge.there is certainly no reason. thanks

Comment: If you set the MySQL data field type to "datetime", then you need to pass the format "Y-m-d H:i:s" to MySQL (you can leave off parts and MySQL will insert defaults). However, passing "d-m-Y H:i:s" will be rejected as "not valid" by MySQL. Check the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

Comment: Databases expect datetime values to be in a certain format. They do *not* expect d-m-Y.

Comment: alright, i have read through it and didn't recognized that there is ONLY one way to insert a datetime format. thanks for anwering.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid DATETIME formats and invalid values will be converted to zero values (e.g. `0000-00-00 00:00:00`). In your case, the given DATETIME format is invalid.

Valid formats are:

- `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (Delimiters can be chosen randomly)
- `YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` (Delimiters can be chosen randomly)
- `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` (String & number format acceptable)
- `YYMMDDHHMMSS` (String & number format acceptable)

For further reading and details about two-digit year conversions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('d/m/y H:i:s',$time);
```

This output the date in the required format without changing the format in database.Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In database the column must be a datetime field and by default it stores data in 0000-00-00 00:00:00 format. One workaround would be to change the database column to varchar and save the data in the format u need.

hope this helps.

Comment: and use strtotime() function to convert varchar to datetime format in php.